# Update Scene.statistics for verts, faces, tris count after modifiers

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, modifiers, polycount

I've written a python batching function that runs though a list of OBJ files. It imports the OBJ, adds some modifiers, then saves. I want to know the statistics at the start and at the end. However, I get the same statistics at the end.

My code looks basically like this:

```
ImportOBJ(filename)
stats_start = bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer)
obj.modifiers.new('DecimateHalf', 'DECIMATE')
obj.modifiers['DecimateHalf'].ratio = 0.5
stats_end = bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer)
```

However, the output is the same.

```
stats_start: 'Collection | objfile | Verts:76,419 | Faces:113,902 | Tris:113,902 | Objects:1/1 | Memory: 54.6 MiB | 2.90.1'
stats_end:   'Collection | objfile | Verts:76,419 | Faces:113,902 | Tris:113,902 | Objects:1/1 | Memory: 54.6 MiB | 2.90.1'
```

I can get the same result with the Python Console by copy pasting these lines so they execute together.

```
bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer)
C.object.modifiers.new('DecimateHalf', 'DECIMATE')
C.object.modifiers['DecimateHalf'].ratio = 0.5
bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer)
```

Which does the same thing, output looks like this:

```
>>> bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer)
'Collection | objfile | Verts:76,419 | Faces:113,902 | Tris:113,902 | Objects:1/1 | Memory: 51.4 MiB | 2.90.1'

>>> C.object.modifiers.new('DecimateHalf', 'DECIMATE')
bpy.data.objects['objfile'].modifiers["DecimateHalf"]

>>> C.object.modifiers['DecimateHalf'].ratio = 0.5
>>> bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer)
'Collection | objfile | Verts:76,419 | Faces:113,902 | Tris:113,902 | Objects:1/1 | Memory: 54.6 MiB | 2.90.1'
```

I've tried updating the layer using `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` but it doesn't work. Please note that I don't want to apply the modifier, as I would like to keep the original import.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to wait a little bit for the dependency graph to update. It might not work for your script but if it doesn't rely on the data to be available right away you can use [Application Timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html) with a very short time span so it executes on the next update cycle.

```
import bpy

def print_stats():
    print(bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer))

print_stats()
bpy.context.object.modifiers.new(type="SUBSURF", name="sub")

bpy.app.timers.register(print_stats, first_interval=0.001)


>>> Scene Collection | Cube.001 | Verts:8 | Faces:6 | Tris:12 | Objects:1/1 | Memory: 19.3 MiB | 3.0.0 Beta
>>> Scene Collection | Cube.001 | Verts:26 | Faces:24 | Tris:48 | Objects:1/1 | Memory: 19.3 MiB | 3.0.0 Beta
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but it didn't work in my script. I probably should have mentioned I'm running the script by launching Blender with the --background flag.

Comment: Maybe you ought to search for a different approach, do you absolutely need this information formatted that way ? You can recreate the statistics by evaluating the objects in the scene

Answer (score 0):

LMB anywhere on the screen works for me

Comment: Hi, dougb, and welcome.. Fair enough. But I think you might have missed the point of the original question, here, to _automate_ the update? Perhaps reconsider the validity of this answer?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.